# Why isn't my angular radio button marked as selected ( i have to click twice)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<li ng-repeat="flagVm in flagVms track by $id(flagVm)">
    <label for="alternative{{$index}}" ng-click="alternativeClicked()">
        <input ng-model="$parent.alternative" value="{{ flagVm.id }}" type="radio" name="alternative{{$index}}" /> 
        <span class="num-times-flagged">(Flagged {{ flagVm.count }} {{ flagVm.count > 1 ? 'times' : 'time' }}) </span>
        Inference Id: 
        <span class="highlighted-id">{{ flagVm.duplicateId }}</span>
    </label>
</li>
```

and

```
$scope.alternativeClicked = function (id) 
{
    //once iterating will probably be the actual flag obj
    $scope.alternativeFound = 'yes';
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I think using `ng-click` with radio is a bad practice.

The better way is to use `ng-change` or `$watch` value change